# Ruby 'tap' method - inside assignment

Tags: ruby

Recently I discovered that `tap` can be used in order to "drily" assign values to new variables; for example, for creating and filling an array, like this:

```
array = [].tap { |ary| ary << 5 if something }
```

This code will push `5` into `array` if `something` is truthy; otherwise, `array` will remain empty.

But I don't understand why after executing this code:

```
array = [].tap { |ary| ary += [5] if something }
```

`array` remains empty. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the first case `array` and `ary` point to the same object. You then mutate that object using the `<<` method. The object that both `array` and `ary` point to is now changed.

In the second case `array` and `ary` again both point to the same array. You now reassign the `ary` variable, so that `ary` now points to a new array. Reassigning `ary` however has no effect on `array`. In ruby reassigning a variable never effects other variables, even if they pointed to the same object before the reassignment.

In other words `array` is still empty for the same reason that `x` won't be 42 in the following example:

```
x = 23
y = x
y = 42 # Changes y, but not x
```

Edit: To append one array to another in-place you can use the `concat` method, which should also be faster than using `+=`.

Comment: ADD: `a += b` works like `a = a + b` – here fact of creation a new object is more obvious.

Comment: @Nakilon: Given that the OP was explicitly talking about assignment, I assumed that that part was clear to him.

Comment: ok, I think I understood; it doesn't work beacuse of the assignment operation. In order to obtain the effect that I want I should do <code>array = [].tap { |ary| [5].each{ |v| ary << 5 } }</code> --- How can you add formatting to your comments??

Comment: @ProGNOMmers: No, need for that. You can just use the `append` method. Sorry that I didn't mention that before.

Comment: The a += b -> a = a + b analogy does not apply for all languages, for example in Python += with a list does not create a new object but an in-place extend. IMHO in-place stuff (in any language) is pretty scary, I wouldn't resort to it except for performance reasons, and create new objects (functional approach) whenever possible.

Comment: "x won't be 42", yes, but because 42 is the perfect answer x should know that and do it anyway. :-)

Comment: @sepp2k : I cannot find `append` method anywhere, maybe you implemented this method and added it to your core extensions in the past, and you forgot it! :D anyway, I implemented it:`

    class Array
      def append(other_array)
        other_array.each { |value| self << value }
      end
    end`

Comment: @ProGNOMmers: It's `concat`, not `append`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 23):

I want to expand on this a bit:

```
array = [].tap { |ary| ary << 5 if something }
```

What this does (assuming `something` is true-ish):

1. assigns `array` to `[]`, an empty array.

   ```
   array.object_id = 2152428060
   ```
2. passes `[]` to the block as `ary`. `ary` and `array` are pointing to the same array object.

   ```
   array.object_id = 2152428060
   ary.object_id = 2152428060
   ```
3. `ary << 5`  << is a mutative method, meaning it will modify the receiving object. It is similar to the idiom of appending `!` to a method call, meaning "modify this in place!", like in `.map` vs `.map!` (though the bang does not hold any intrinsic meaning on its own in a method name). `ary` has 5 inserted, so `ary` = `array` = `[5]`

   ```
   array.object_id = 2152428060
   ary.object_id = 2152428060
   ```

We end with `array` being equal to `[5]`

In the second example:

```
array = [].tap{ |ary| ary += [5] if something }
```

1. same
2. same
3. `ary += 5` `+=` is short for `ary = ary + 5`, so it is first modification (`+`) and then assignment (`=`), in that order. It gives the appearance of modifying an object in place, but it actually does not. It creates an entirely new object.

   ```
   array.object_id = 2152428060
   ary.object_id = 2152322420
   ```

So we end with `array` as the original object, an empty array with `object_id=2152428060` , and `ary`, an array with one item containing 5 with `object_id = 2152322420`. Nothing happens to `ary` after this. It is uninvolved with the original assignment of `array`, that has already happened. Tap executes the block after `array` has been assigned.